# Angular how to use google storage api

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-chrome-storage

I am not getting to use chrome's storage extension. I keep getting: chrome.storage is undefined.

Even I get the error, it still stores, the array I wanted to store.
This block is somehow working:

```
  chrome.storage.local.set({'projectsToNotif': projectsForNotif}, function() {
                        console.log('Projects to be notified are marked');
                    });
```

I have a manifest file where I have the following:

```
{
  "name": "Juju Web App",
  "short_name": "iBrand Web App",
  "display": "standalone",
  "description": "App for internal use.",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Web apps can't use API for Chrome extensions.

Comment: Yes, you can develop all the required features of your chrome extension inside the angular application.

Answer (score 0):

I see where the problem is, you are missing some fields from your manifest.json file, updated them with these new fields.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Juju Web App",
  "description": "App for internal use.",
  "display": "standalone",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src ‘self’ ‘unsafe-eval’; object-src ‘self’",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
  "assets/css/* ",
  "assets/js/*",
  "assets/fonts/*"
  ]
 }
```

Now for accessing chrome storage I recommend build a service that will handle it here is the basic service that will handle chrome storage API.

If you don't want to build your own Service you can use this package [ng2-chrome-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-chrome-storage)

```
import { Injectable, NgZone, Optional } from '@angular/core';

export class Settings {
    storeKey: string = 'hhappsettings';  // identifier to be used as a key for storage
    data: any = {};
  }

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChromeStorageService {

    storeKey = ''; // chrome storage key
    config: any;     // holds settings

    constructor(private zone: NgZone, @Optional() _settings: Settings) {
        let usethisSettings = (_settings)? _settings : new Settings();
        this.config = usethisSettings.data;
        this.storeKey = usethisSettings.storeKey;
      }

      // to be used inside a resolver
  load() {
    return this.getChrome(this.storeKey, this.config).then((data: any) => {
      this.config = data;
      return data;
    });
  }


   // remove a key
   remove(key: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (window['chrome'] !== undefined && window['chrome'].storage !== undefined) {
        window['chrome'].storage.sync.remove(/* String or Array */key, () => this.zone.run(() => {
          resolve(true);
        }));
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  }


  getChrome(key: string, defaults = {}): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (window['chrome'] !== undefined && window['chrome'].storage !== undefined) {
        let saveObj = {};
        saveObj[key] = defaults;
        window['chrome'].storage.sync.get(/* String or Array */saveObj, (data) => this.zone.run(() => {
         resolve(data[key]);
        }));
      } else {
        let object =  (localStorage.getItem(key) === null) ? defaults : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        resolve(object);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

hope this answered your question :) .